# Angular 4 + Spring boot + ContentNegotiatingViewResolver

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an application where I am using Angular 4 with Spring boot. It has Home page, Dashboard, Inspection, Report pages etc... When I click on any link in the nav menu, it goes to that page. When I hit localhost:8080, it goes to Home page.

Earlier we didn't have any View Resolver. We got a requirement to download Excel/PDF/CSV in one of Report pages by clicking on hyper links. So I added a Configuration class and Controller and tested, it is working fine (means I can download excel/pdf/csv) when I hit direct urls. But when I hit localhost:8080, instead of showing me the Home page, it downloading the Excel. I am sure I am missing some configuration. Any help please...  I can share more code when requested...

direct urls: localhost:8080/api/inspDefectHistReportDownload.xls

WebConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer
                .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .favorPathExtension(true);
    }

    /*
     * Configure ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);

        // Define all possible view resolvers
        List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<>();

        //resolvers.add(csvViewResolver());
        resolvers.add(excelViewResolver());
        //resolvers.add(pdfViewResolver());

        resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
        return resolver;
    }

    /*
     * Configure View resolver to provide XLS output using Apache POI library to
     * generate XLS output for an object content
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver excelViewResolver() {
        return new ExcelViewResolver();
    }

    /*
     * Configure View resolver to provide Csv output using Super Csv library to
     * generate Csv output for an object content
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver csvViewResolver() {
        return new CsvViewResolver();
    }

    /*
     * Configure View resolver to provide Pdf output using iText library to
     * generate pdf output for an object content
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver pdfViewResolver() {
        return new PdfViewResolver();
    }
```

Of course I have ReportController, ExcelView... and ExcelViewResolver.java etc...  (If requested, I can post these classes as well)

Comment: I have explained and put all code and given so much details, still I got Downvote. Now I am not able to ask any question. Can you please Upvote the question or let me know how I can improve to get upvote...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long investigation, I found the below code working for me. Now I can go to home page and other screens by resepective urls and on click of hyper link in a particular screen, I can download the desired excel.

WebConfiguration.java

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer
    .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .ignoreAcceptHeader(true);
}

 @Override
 public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableContentNegotiation(
            new ExcelView()
    );
}
```